# Not receiving input value in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I m passing parameters in stored procedures but unable to fetch records when filtering with inputs.But when I store that Input into variables and pass it to fetch record I get the records.why?
Here is stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Demo_akg$$

CREATE PROCEDURE Demo_akg (IN ip_Id VARCHAR (100))

BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM table_namel IAS WHERE Id = ip_Id;

END$$

DELIMITER;
```

I tried to take input in variable and pass it to where clause ti fetch records .
Here is the method that I have tried. And it works why?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Demo_akg$$

CREATE PROCEDURE Demo_akg (IN ip_Id VARCHAR (100))

BEGIN 
Select ip_Id into @ip_Id;
SELECT * FROM table_namel IAS WHERE Id = @ip_Id;

END$$

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't work the same way? There's no difference between using a local variable and a user variable in the query.

Comment: Right I m having the same doubt it's the same.

Comment: Did you mean to say "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Yes when I run without user variable I get 0 records but when using that variable I am able to get records.

Comment: Please add the CALL statements.

Comment: Call Demo_akg('10');

Comment: And if I change the type from varchar to Int then also I m able get the records. So is there any issue with string

Comment: The datatype of the parameter `ip_Id` should match the datatype of the `table_namel.Id`.

Comment: Ok got it now there was type mismatch for me Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to say what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't know the structure of table_namel, but it seems the table have a field with same name as input parameter.

To prevent that use the parameters with some prefix/surfix:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Demo_akg$$
CREATE PROCEDURE Demo_akg (IN p_ip_Id VARCHAR (100))
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM table_namel IAS WHERE Id = p_ip_Id;

END$$

DELIMITER;
```